# Why would socket.write hang indefinitely?

Tags: ruby, sockets, memcached

What would make a write call to a [TCPSocket](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/socket/rdoc/TCPSocket.html) hang indefinitely?

```
lotsOfBytes = # a really large number of bytes, like 1 or 2 MB of data

socket = TCPSocket.new # some config
socket.write(lotsOfBytes) # this line hangs
```

I am trying to [debug an issue](https://github.com/petergoldstein/dalli/issues/776) where a `get_multi` operation sent to memcached with a large number of keys hangs indefinitely, and it does so on a [line that resembles](https://github.com/petergoldstein/dalli/blob/31dabf19d3dd94b348a00a59fe5a7b8fa80ce3ad/lib/dalli/server.rb#L563) that code snippet. I'm trying to better understand how the low-level sockets on which this library is built are expected to work.

Answer (score -1):

What are the values of following attributes on your TCPSocket:

- Keep-alive activated and what value is set?
- Timeout set and what value is set?

If you will do a Wireshark dump, it's much better so see what happens before hanging connection.

Answer (score -1):

- tcpdump? are there any attempts to send anything?
- netstat - for see output queue.
- does it work on a small number of bytes in your environment?